# What is the meaning of "REM ORUINE PANDO"

Tags: etymology, latin-to-english-translation

I have an old silver jewellery box, in the bottom left hand corner is an arm holding a spear, with a banner underneath, with the words

> REM ORUINE PANDO

The I in ORUINE could possibly be an L, hard to tell.
I was wondering if anyone could tell me what it means? Is it even Latin?

Answer (score 14):

That "U" is probably a "D": *rem ordine pando*. This is a quote from Vergil's *Aeneid* 3.179 and means "I explained the whole thing [i.e. the whole story] in order."

Comment: I’d like to note that _pando_ is present tense, not past tense; although in its original context in the Aeneid, it is used as a dramatic present (historic present) and does refer to the past.

Answer (score 10):

Presumably (as far as one can presume anything without an image of the object in question) it says “rem ordine pando”, a quotation from Vergil’s Aeneid 3:179.